# Scheme -Trouble returning a list of lists

Tags: list, scheme, nested-lists

This function is supposed to take 3 lists, and return a list of lists where each outputted sub list contains the 3 beginning elements of the input lists.

So the function would return a list ((1 2 10) (3 4 20) (9 8 30)).

I can't get the formatting to come out the way I want to. Any ideas on how I could get this to work out?

```
enter code here
```

Comment: You could actually just define this as `(map list l ll lll)`, but that might be missing the point.

Comment: @AlexisKing Or even as a variant on the classic transpose `(define (transpose . lists) (apply map list lists))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's workout a few examples:

```
; (zip3 '()  '()  '())          == ()                   
; (zip3 '(9) '(8) '(30))        == ((9 8 30))
; (zip3 '(3 9) '(4 8) '(20 30)) == ((3 4 20) (9 8 30)) 
                                == (cons '(3 4 20) (zip3 '(9) '(8) '(30))
```

This inspires the following:

```
(define (zip3 xs ys zs)
  (cond
    [(null? xs)  '()]
    [else        (let ([x   (car xs)] [y   (car ys)] [z   (car zs)]
                       [xs* (cdr xs)] [ys* (cdr ys)] [zs* (cdr zs)])
                   (cons (list x y z) (zip3 xs* ys* zs*)))]))

(zip3 '(1 3 9) '(2 4 8) '(10 20 30))
```